# html_entity_decode not working How to resolve?

Tags: php

PHP:

```
html_entity_decode('&#x3C;p style=&#x22;font-size:18px;color:#ff0000&#x22;&#x3E;Cancelled&#x3C;/p&#x3E;');
htmlspecialchars_decode('&#x3C;p style=&#x22;font-size:18px;color:#ff0000&#x22;&#x3E;Cancelled&#x3C;/p&#x3E;');
```

Output:

```
&lt;p style="font-size:18px;color:#ff0000"&gt;Cancelled&lt;/p&gt;
```

Hello, Everyone, I tried both solutions but this making it to a string instead of HTML. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Both examples seem to work rather well → when not used in void context (= no output or assignment anywhere). Maybe you could share a few more thoughts on what you meant by "to a string instead of HTML" ?

Comment: https://eval.in/938142 and https://eval.in/938140 both were working

Answer (score 0):

Simply by adding echo:

```
echo html_entity_decode('&#x3C;p style=&#x22;font-size:18px;color:#ff0000&#x22;&#x3E;Cancelled&#x3C;/p&#x3E;');
echo htmlspecialchars_decode('&#x3C;p style=&#x22;font-size:18px;color:#ff0000&#x22;&#x3E;Cancelled&#x3C;/p&#x3E;');
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the expected output?